# How to compile uefi application using gnu-efi?

Tags: uefi, gnu-efi

I tried to compile uefi code using `gnu-efi`. But I don't understand how to compile my uefi application code.

I get `gnu-efi` 3.0.2, decompress and type `make && make install`. I write hello world code:

```
#include <efi.h>
#include <efilib.h>

EFI_STATUS efi_main (EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *SystemTable) {
    InitializeLib(ImageHandle, SystemTable);
    Print(L"Hello, world!\n");

    return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

My OS is Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Include the gnu-efi  files

   ```
   #include <efi.h> 
   #include <efilib.h>
   ```

   it looks like your includes where removed by SO
2. create the make file;

> If you were building a "Hello, World" program for Linux in a Linux
>   environment, you could compile it without a Makefile. Building the
>   program in Linux for EFI, though, is essentially a cross-compilation
>   operation. As such, it necessitates using unusual compilation and
>   linker options, as well as a post-linking operation to convert the
>   program into a form that the EFI will accept. Although you could type
>   all the relevant commands by hand, a Makefile helps a lot.

```
ARCH            = $(shell uname -m | sed s,i[3456789]86,ia32,)

OBJS            = main.o
TARGET          = hello.efi

EFIINC          = /usr/include/efi
EFIINCS         = -I$(EFIINC) -I$(EFIINC)/$(ARCH) -I$(EFIINC)/protocol
LIB             = /usr/lib64
EFILIB          = /usr/lib64/gnuefi
EFI_CRT_OBJS    = $(EFILIB)/crt0-efi-$(ARCH).o
EFI_LDS         = $(EFILIB)/elf_$(ARCH)_efi.lds

CFLAGS          = $(EFIINCS) -fno-stack-protector -fpic \
          -fshort-wchar -mno-red-zone -Wall 
ifeq ($(ARCH),x86_64)
  CFLAGS += -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER
endif

LDFLAGS         = -nostdlib -znocombreloc -T $(EFI_LDS) -shared \
          -Bsymbolic -L $(EFILIB) -L $(LIB) $(EFI_CRT_OBJS) 

all: $(TARGET)

hello.so: $(OBJS)
    ld $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@ -lefi -lgnuefi

%.efi: %.so
    objcopy -j .text -j .sdata -j .data -j .dynamic \
        -j .dynsym  -j .rel -j .rela -j .reloc \
        --target=efi-app-$(ARCH) $^ $@
```

reference:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-programming/hello.html

Comment: @Thecoffee17thcup can you let me know how can i build that in Ubuntu ? I keep having "fatal error: efi.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: that's an easy one. your compiler cannot see `efi.h`, check your `make` file; `EFIINC          = /usr/include/efi`  should point the required gnu-efi header files.

Comment: What `-fpic` for?

Comment: Position Independent Code read https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:AMD64/Fixing_-fPIC_Errors_Guide#What_is_PIC.3F

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu 18.04, these two lines:

```
LIB             = /usr/lib64

EFILIB          = /usr/lib64/gnuefi
```

need to be changed to:

```
LIB             = /usr/lib

EFILIB          = /usr/lib
```