# How to compile UEFI Applications with GNU-UEFI in Windows?

Tags: uefi

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514866/how-to-compile-uefi-application-using-gnu-efi) but I believe the setup cannot be used in Windows. Is there anyway I can build UEFI apps in WIndows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gnu-efi was created to make it easy to build UEFI applications/drivers from a unix-like operating system.

If you are on Windows, the traditional way would be to use Visual Studio (community edition is fine) and the open source TianoCore EDK2 project. [Instructions can be found in the TianoCore wiki](https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/Windows-systems).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use GNU-EFI on Windows you can take a look at https://github.com/pbatard/uefi-simple
It is already pre-configured for VisualStudio, you just need to press "Play" (F5).